# Invalid use of property Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 20
End Sub
```

This simple code is giving error when I compile it. 
`activesheet`. works fine.

I want to know whats resulting in an error and how to fix it...

looks like it's not identifying the sheets, workbook etc.

Comment: how are you executing this? It seems to work fine when i run it

Comment: There must be more code? I can't see how you would get **that** error just from that code.

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on which error you get. There can be 2 issues:

#### 1. Workbook not specified

You have more than one workbook and Excel is looking in the wrong workbook for your sheet named "Sheet1", then you need to specify the workbook.

```
Workbooks("my-workbook").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 20
```

or if it is in the workbook where the code is running at it is better to use

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 20
```

Note that you should avoid `ActiveWorkbook` which is not very reliable.

#### 2. Wrong worksheet name

There is no worksheet named `Sheet1`. Check your worksheet names. Note that there are different ways to specify a worksheet.

- **Specify by number**

  ```
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
  ```

  This uses the position of the worksheet in the tab bar below the worksheets. Note that is not very reliable because position can easily be changed by moving the tabs around.
- **Specify by tab name**

  ```
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
  ```

  This is probably the most common method. The worksheet is specified by its tab name. This is more reliable than by number.
- **Specify by VBA name**

  ```
    Sheet1.Range("A1")
  ```

  Here the VBA name of the sheet is used. This name can only be changed in the VB editor and is not visible to the user, and has nothing to do with the tab name. Using this ensures that the VBA code still works on the desired worksheet even if a user changes the tab name of the worksheet.

So if the tab name is `Sheet1` its VBA name can be `Sheet5` and it can be on position `3` in the tab bar.
Using this example …

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Sheet5.Range("A1")
Worksheets(3).Range("A1")
```

… are all 3 accessing the exact same worksheet just by different names. So better to use meaningful names (and no numbers) here to not confuse.

Comment: One of the best explanations about sheet names i've read, thank you.